# How to get the pixel count of a certain object using Image Segmentation with Watershed [OpenCV]

Tags: java, android, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to get the total pixel count of the leaf which was segemented using Watershed Algorithm(Just saw it in net). The problem is that **it returns the same count of pixels from the original image whenever I am using Mat::Total()**.

I thought if I followed the steps in the tutorial from [this](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_watershed/py_watershed.html) site I can use the Mat in order to subtract the leaf Image from the background.

I really need to get the pixel count of the object as I will use it to also get different colors from that leaf(ex. getting yellow pixels(count) from the leaf).

Please refer to my code and help me find the bugs I should resolve.

```
    private Mat getSureLeaf(Mat originalMat) {
    //Step 1: GrayScale
    /* IMAGE SEGMENTATION USING WATERSHED ALGORITHM */
    //Create a Mat Object using originalPicture as is:
    /* OTSU'S BINARIZATION */
    Mat grayscaleMat = new Mat();
    //check if i dont need to load_image as grayscale, if cvtColor does does work or vice versa:
    Imgproc.cvtColor(originalMat, grayscaleMat, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    Imgproc.threshold(grayscaleMat, grayscaleMat, 0, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY_INV + Imgproc.THRESH_OTSU);

    Mat foregroundMat = new Mat();
    Imgproc.erode(grayscaleMat, foregroundMat, new Mat(),new Point(-1,-1),2);

    Mat backgroundMat = new Mat();
    Imgproc.dilate(grayscaleMat, backgroundMat, new Mat(), new Point(-1,-1), 3);
    Imgproc.threshold(backgroundMat, backgroundMat, 1,128, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY_INV);

    //Markers image:
    Mat markersMat = new Mat(grayscaleMat.size(), CvType.CV_8U, new Scalar(0));
    Core.add(foregroundMat, backgroundMat, markersMat);

    Mat finalMat = markersMat;
    finalMat.convertTo(markersMat, CvType.CV_32S);
    Imgproc.watershed(originalMat, finalMat);
    //then return as CV_8U:
    // finalMat.convertTo(finalMat, CvType.CV_8U);

    leafMatPixCount = finalMat.total();
    Log.i(TAG, "Leaf Mat Pixel Count: " + leafMatPixCount);

return finalMat;
}
```

Here is the Log I have:

```
09-04 17:47:00.027 10392-10392/com.estaris.module_colordetection I/MainActivity: Original Pixel Count: 252480
09-04 17:47:00.090 10392-10392/com.estaris.module_colordetection I/MainActivity: Leaf Mat Pixel Count: 252480
```

PS: I am expecting that the watershed function would already deduct the object from its background. I'll really appreciate comments and suggestions. Thank you in advanced.

**UPDATE:**

[This](http://imageshack.com/a/img922/3240/bXyk5R.png) screenshot shows the original image and finalMat's image. FinalMat's background shows gray area, so I assume it's been excluded from the white mask(foreground, if I am doing it right).

Again, my question is: **Did finalMat really segmented the background from the leaf, as it shows that the leaf is colored white and the background was gray? And if so, How can I use the finalMat to count the pixels of the leaf itself being excluded from the background(which the tutorial claimed it does)?**

I really need the leaf to be excluded from the background so I can use it to count the green colors of the leaf and yellow, and a lot more.

Comment: Do you want *color count* or *pixel count*? Also post your images.

Comment: Hello, @Zinarod. :) Thank you for responding. I updated my question.